# How to read an XML file in a Visual C++ application?

Tags: xml, visual-c++, com, atl

How to read an XML file in a Visual C++ application?

I need to read an XML file in a Visual Studio 2003 C++ COM ATL application - unmanaged code. What library should I use: msxml, xmllite, other?

I need to check that the xml satisfies its xsd I've defined and then read it.

Sample code welcomed ;)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of choices, we use the [Xerces-C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) library which covers all the options, but isn't the most light weight of choices, but offers a lot of flexibility.

For starters you need to decide if you want a DOM style parser or a SAX style (event driver) parser.

Answer (score 4):

I used [tinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/index.html). It is very restricted(no DTDs, no XSL), but it loads XML-Files into doms, is very small and fast. If you just want to **read** an xml-file to extract information out of it: that is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a huge fan of [CMarkup](http://www.firstobject.com/dn_markup.htm).  It has MFC and STL string versions and is written in unmanaged C++; ideal for all of my situations.

There's also a wrapper class for MSXML.  There's a downloadable version available to experiment with and several samples/tutorials available online.